# SQL Server : Insert trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I have a problem with trigger below. Thanks for any help.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upper_case ON osoba
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @imie VARCHAR(25)
    DECLARE @new_imie VARCHAR(25)
    DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT imie FROM INSERTED

    OPEN my_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @imie

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            @new_imie = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@imie, 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@imie, 2,LEN(@imie))
        END
        UPDATE osoba
        SET imie = @new_imie WHERE imie = @imie
END
```

The error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure upper_case, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near '@new_imie'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure upper_case, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: Using a **cursor** inside a **trigger** is about the worst thing you can do in SQL Server. You should avoid this at all costs! A trigger should be very lean, very efficient, and run for the absolute minimum of time.....

Comment: Did you close and deallocate your cursor?

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  It doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Looks like it capitalises the first letter of each updated `imie`.

Comment: should be calling fetch next inside the loop as well. Insert more than one record, it will never exit the loop.

Comment: @marc_s. Not a clever idea in any dbms...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a cursor for this.

You can use an `UPDATE` statement that affects all rows at once instead of processing them one by one.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upper_case
ON osoba
AFTER INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      UPDATE O
      SET    imie = UPPER(SUBSTRING(I.imie, 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(I.imie, 2, LEN(I.imie))
      FROM   INSERTED I
             JOIN osoba O
               ON I.imie = O.imie
  END
```

Comment: Just to emphasize, DML statements in triggers always need to work for an arbitrary count of rows (not just one).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SET` when you assign `@new_imie` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx)):

```
SET @new_imie = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@imie, 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@imie, 2,LEN(@imie));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to @new_imie requires the SET keyword in front of it...

```
   SET @new_imie = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@imie, 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@imie, 2,LEN(@imie))
```